# Lots of files appearing in my Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Objects and files names in my S3 bucket changed from my selected names to those displayed in the screenshot below.. And now when I update a file, it uploads successfully but doesn't change, the date modified is not changed neither are the changes in the codes are visible on the web page. Can someone please help me find out what happens to this bucket and how can I fix it?

[image: See the file and object names are all strange]

Comment: Amazon S3 objects **do not** change their names without something causing it to happen. Somebody (or some application) with access to your account would have made the changes. Also, the fact that you upload a file but the date remains unchanged and the content is not changed, suggests that you are **not** uploading the files (or at least not into the location you are viewing). **How are you uploading the files?** Is it via the S3 management console, or via a 3rd-party program (judging from the filenames).

Comment: The filenames you see are those that have changed and I don't know how, my filenames were simple like 'analytics.html'. And I don't use any third party program, I simply drag and drop the changed files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The files you are showing are created by [Amazon S3 bucket logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html), which creates **log files** of access requests to Amazon S3.

Logging is activated within the **Properties** panel of your bucket, where you can nominate a target bucket and prefix for the logs.

So, your files are **not** being renamed. Rather, they are additional log files that are generated by Amazon S3.

If they are in the same location as your files, things will get confusing! Your files are still in there, but probably later in the naming scheme.

I would recommend:

- Go into the bucket's properties
- If you do not need the logs, then disable bucket logging
- If you wish to keep the logs, configure them to write to a different bucket, or the same bucket but with a prefix (directory)
- Delete or move the existing log files so that you will be left with just your non-log files

Comment: Pretty terrible setup by Amazon here. I'm dealing with this now. I can't find the directories I was using.